# Creating new dataframes by subsetting and reference two dataframes in R

Tags: r

I have two data sets. One with employee preferences and one with a list of potential matches. For each employee, I want to find the matches and create a new dataset for each. The dataset can be one large comprehensive set that can then be split by person, or separate ones from the beginning.

```
 df1:

> emplid= c("empl1","empl2","empl3") 
> c1 = c("HR", "Finance", "HR")
>  c2 = c("x", "y", "z") 
>  c3 = c("a","b","C")
>  df1 = data.frame(emplid, c1, c2, c3)

df2: 
>  job = c("job1", "job2", "job3", "job4") 
>  c4 = c("HR", "HR", "Finance", "Finance") 
>  c5 = c("x", "x", "y", "z") 
>  c6 = c("a","b", "b","c")
>  df2 = data.frame(job, c4, c5, c6)
```

The result would be

```
emplid      job          c4     c5        c6
empl1       job1         HR      x        a
empl3       job4         Finance y        b
```

The above result could be combined, but ultimately I will split it up.

I've only successfully been able to do this when I have only one row in the first dataframe, but that will not be the case. I've tried loops but with no success.

Comment: what columns are you matching on in each df?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest renaming your columns so that they match. Here's an example of what I would do:

```
emplid= c("empl1","empl2","empl3") 
c1 = c("HR", "Finance", "HR")
c2 = c("x", "y", "x") 
c3 = c("a","b","a")
df1 = data.frame(emplid, c1, c2, c3)

job = c("job1", "job2", "job3", "job4") 
c1 = c("HR", "HR", "Finance", "Finance") 
c2 = c("x", "x", "y", "z") 
c3 = c("a","b", "b","c")
df2 = data.frame(job, c1, c2, c3)

temp = df1 %>%
  group_by(c1,c2,c3)

df2 = df2 %>%
  right_join(temp, by = c('c1','c2','c3'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a data.table solution.

```
df1[df2, on = c(c1="c4", c2="c5",c3="c6"),nomatch=0]
```